# imageline, imagegif, imagecolorallocate doesn't work in hosting, but in xampp it does

Tags: php, mysql, image, graphics, hosting

So, I use functions imageline, imagegif and imagecolorallocate to draw some graphic. It works perfectly in xampp, however, it doesn't work in vps hosting. What should I enable at hosting that it could work, because I believe there is problem exactly in hosting.

Thank you very much.

P.S. English lesson: Should I say in hosting or at hosting? :)

P.S.S. PHP GD is already downloaded, but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of GD is installed? What disto is you vps? What version of php?

Comment: Also, define doesn't work. Is there an error? Does the page 'white out' showing no output? Are the images written at all, or incorrectly?

Comment: @xzyfer: the lines are "written" incorectly. All versions are the newest. What is disto?

Comment: Sorry is OS version, you mentioned it below as CentOS 5.5 x86. Best to add this to your question. Also and a complete description of what you are trying to do with gd, what is actually happening, and if possible a code sample. Your question is very vague and as you've pointed out, it is in fact working, just not working as intended, so we need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the OS would have helped to answer the question better, php-gd or php5-gd is the name of the package you are looking for.

Comment: I have fixed that by myself, it was my fault :)

Comment: So did you solve your problem (if yes can i get that bounty :) )? If not, please state what (does not) happen. For example , do you have extension=gd.so in the correct php.ini? Run a script containing phpinfo() in the environment you have problems with and see path to php.ini (also phpinfo shows whether gd is loaded) and whether it has GIF support. If it doesnt you need to recompile AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that php_gd2 extension is enable in your local xampp server but not in your hosting server. Please check the php extension list if this extension is enable on your hosting server. If it's not enabled then you must ask the admin to enable the extension and make the gd functions workable.